# my state is giving an empty/or undefined although the reducer is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to fetch response from this api with redux thunks via three actions: 'fetchProductsPending, fetchProductsSuccess, fetchProductsError'

here's the fetch request:

```
function fetchProducts() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsPending());
        fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches')
        .then(res => res.json()
        
        )
        .then(
          res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(res.products));
            return res.products;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchProductsError(error));
        })
    }
}

export default fetchProducts;
```

I initialized the state as empty array:

```
const initialState = {
  pending: false,
  products: [],
  error: null
}
const middlewares = [thunk];

export const store=createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

and here's the reducer:

```
export function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: true
            }
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                products: action.products
            }
        case FETCH_PRODUCTS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                pending: false,
                error: action.error
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

here's a sandbox for the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sunset-wxefc?file=/src/style.js

Comment: Seems like there's multiple issues in the codesandbox, but `this.pending` is not what you think it is. Which is one reason why it's good to make sure you've adequately nailed down the problem space, because it's difficult to know what other problems there may be, and impossible to get started answering the question w/o having to click away. Unrelated, but returning `res.products` from `fetchProducts`'s returned function may not be helpful.

Comment: This.pending was for a loading indicator and auite unrelated to the response

Comment: My point about `pending` was that it's being pulled from state, but referenced through `this`. You might want to create the smallest example that shows the issue rather than having unrelated code present.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong.

You are selecting `state.products`, but your rootReducer mounts the `productReducer` at `state.productData.products`, so you'd have to select that instead.

Generally: this is a very outdated style of redux that we mostly encouraging to learn for "what is going on under the hood", but not for really writing apps with any more, as it leads to a lot of unnecessary code. So you might be following a very outdated tutorial. For a more up-to-date apporach, please take a look at [the official redux tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)